# "trouble writing output: Too many field references: 70185; max is 65536. You may try using --multi-dex option." when building Android project

Tags: android, apk, android-library, dex, apklib

I hit this error and found no hits for the error message, so I thought I'd share the solution I came up with to save anyone else facing the problem repeating my work.

When writing a new Android library (apklib) for use in a (large) application, I'm getting the following error during dexing when I add my new project as a dependency:

> trouble writing output: Too many field references: 70185; max is 65536.
>   You may try using --multi-dex option.
>   References by package:
>   <...long list of packages with field counts elided...>

The particular build step it fails on is:

```
java -jar $ANDROID_SDK/build-tools/19.0.3/lib/dx.jar --dex \
--output=$PROJECT_HOME/target/classes.dex \
<... long list of apklib and jar dependencies elided ...>
```

Using `--multi-dex` as recommended by the error message might be a solution, but I'm not the owner of the application project and it already has a large complex build process that I would hesitate to change regardless.

I can reproduce this problem with a no-op test library project that has literally no fields, but in the error output it's listed as having 6000+ fields.  Of the packages listed in the error output, there are a handful with similar 6k+ field counts, but then the vast majority have more plausible <1k field counts.

This problem is similar to the "Too many methods" problem that [Facebook famously hacked their way around](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-dalvik-patch-for-facebook-for-android/10151345597798920).  The FB solution seems insane, and the only other solutions I've found (e.g., [this Android bug ticket](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7147), [or this one](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20814), [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15509415/85950), [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15337213/85950)) all involve changing the main app's code which is well beyond the scope of what I want to do.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to change the [package](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package) in the AndroidManifest to match the main application's package.

A manifest like this:

```
<manifest package="com.example.testlibrary" ...
```

resulted in 6k+ fields and build failure.  Changing it to match the main application's package

```
<manifest package="com.example.mainapplication" ...
```

resulted in the project building successfully.

Note that only the package in the manifest is changing, I did not make any changes to the library's Java source or its layout (the Java package was still com.example.testlibrary with directory structure to match).

I hypothesize that the different package name is causing all the Android fields to be included again under that package.  All the packages in the error listing with 6k+ fields had a different package name than the main application.

I also (later, grr), found [this blog post](http://androidthoughts.wordpress.com/2014/03/28/dx-trouble-writing-output-too-many-fields-conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-2/) which details the same problem and the eventual same solution.

Comment: How do I do this?  I tried to rename the package to something else, but I still have the same error,....  I could really use additional information on how you got this to work