# Java.exe exited with code 2 in android app built in VS 2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, android-multidex

I have built an android app using xamarin in VS2015. I was able to release first version of app on google play service.

The other day, I tried to fix the problems and modified some UI, added some xml files and activities.

**But I got the error java.exe exited with code 2 in debug mode when I build the project whereas building was successful in release mode.**

I tried changing HeapSize 1G to 2G found no difference.
I tried to enable ProGuard but found disabled by default.
I went through enabling MultiDex, it lead me another error that file not found error.
I even tried deleting bin and obj folder and rebuilt again but no luck!

This is the error

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       "java.exe" exited with code 2.  WebSchoolAndroid    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets   2152
```

and in line 2152 I have

```
 <!-- Compile java code to dalvik -->
  <CompileToDalvik 
    Condition="'$(UseJackAndJill)'!='True'"
    DxJarPath="$(DxJarPath)"
    JavaToolPath="$(JavaToolPath)"
    JavaMaximumHeapSize="$(JavaMaximumHeapSize)"
    JavaOptions="$(JavaOptions)"
    ClassesOutputDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android\bin\classes"
    ToolPath="$(DxToolPath)"
    ToolExe="$(DxToolExe)"
    UseDx="$(UseDx)"
    MultiDexEnabled="$(AndroidEnableMultiDex)"
    MultiDexMainDexListFile="$(_AndroidMainDexListFile)"
    JavaLibrariesToCompile="@(_JavaLibrariesToCompileForAppDx)"
    OptionalObfuscatedJarFile="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\__proguard_output__.jar"
  />
```

From Diagnostic Output

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\\bin\java.exe -Xmx1G -jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Universal\AndroidSDK\build-tools\24.0.3\\lib\dx.jar --no-strict --dex --output=obj\Debug\android\bin obj\Debug\android\bin\classes "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\mono.android.jar" obj\Debug\__library_projects__\PdfViewBinding\library_project_imports\bin\android-pdfview.jar obj\Debug\__library_projects__\PhotoViewBinding\library_project_imports\bin\photoview.jar obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Square.OkHttp\library_project_imports\okhttp-2.4.0.jar obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Square.OkIO\library_project_imports\okio-1.5.0.jar obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Square.Picasso\library_project_imports\picasso-2.5.2.jar obj\Debug\__library_projects__\UrlImageViewHelper\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\__library_projects__\WebSchoolAndroid.Bindings\library_project_imports\skyepub.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\24.2.1\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat\24.2.1\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat\24.2.1\embedded\libs\internal_impl-24.2.1.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI\24.2.1\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI\24.2.1\embedded\libs\internal_impl-24.2.1.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils\24.2.1\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils\24.2.1\embedded\libs\internal_impl-24.2.1.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\24.2.1\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment\24.2.1\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment\24.2.1\embedded\libs\internal_impl-24.2.1.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat\24.2.1\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat\24.2.1\embedded\libs\internal_impl-24.2.1.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\24.2.1\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\24.2.1\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\24.2.1\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\24.2.1\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\24.2.1\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Firebase.Common\9.6.1\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Firebase.Iid\9.6.1\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging\9.6.1\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base\9.6.1\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement\9.6.1\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks\9.6.1\embedded\classes.jar  (TaskId:294)
1>   (TaskId:294)
1>  trouble writing output: Too many field references: 65549; max is 65536. (TaskId:294)
1>  You may try using --multi-dex option. (TaskId:294)
1>  References by package: (TaskId:294)
1>       2 android.accounts (TaskId:294)
1>      29 android.app (TaskId:294)
1>       1 android.content (TaskId:294)
1>      32 android.content.pm (TaskId:294)
1>       9 android.content.res (TaskId:294)
1>       3 android.database (TaskId:294)
1>      51 android.graphics (TaskId:294)
1>       2 android.media (TaskId:294)
1>       1 android.media.browse (TaskId:294)
1>       2 android.net (TaskId:294)
1>      17 android.os (TaskId:294)
1>       3 android.print (TaskId:294)
1>       1 android.provider (TaskId:294)
1>       8 android.runtime (TaskId:294)
1>    2410 android.support.compat (TaskId:294)
1>    2410 android.support.coreui (TaskId:294)
1>    2410 android.support.coreutils (TaskId:294)
1>    2410 android.support.design (TaskId:294)
1>      58 android.support.design.internal (TaskId:294)
1>     679 android.support.design.widget (TaskId:294)
1>    2410 android.support.fragment (TaskId:294)
1>    2563 android.support.graphics.drawable (TaskId:294)
1>    2410 android.support.graphics.drawable.animated (TaskId:294)
1>    2410 android.support.mediacompat (TaskId:294)
1>    2410 android.support.v4 (TaskId:294)
1>      13 android.support.v4.accessibilityservice (TaskId:294)
1>      17 android.support.v4.animation (TaskId:294)
1>     863 android.support.v4.app (TaskId:294)
1>     111 android.support.v4.content (TaskId:294)
1>       1 android.support.v4.content.pm (TaskId:294)
1>       1 android.support.v4.content.res (TaskId:294)
1>       9 android.support.v4.graphics (TaskId:294)
1>      41 android.support.v4.graphics.drawable (TaskId:294)
1>       4 android.support.v4.hardware.display (TaskId:294)
1>      12 android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint (TaskId:294)
1>      10 android.support.v4.internal.view (TaskId:294)
1>     350 android.support.v4.media (TaskId:294)
1>     300 android.support.v4.media.session (TaskId:294)
1>       7 android.support.v4.net (TaskId:294)
1>      19 android.support.v4.os (TaskId:294)
1>      63 android.support.v4.print (TaskId:294)
1>       9 android.support.v4.provider (TaskId:294)
1>      55 android.support.v4.text (TaskId:294)
1>       6 android.support.v4.text.util (TaskId:294)
1>     102 android.support.v4.util (TaskId:294)
1>     433 android.support.v4.view (TaskId:294)
1>     137 android.support.v4.view.accessibility (TaskId:294)
1>       8 android.support.v4.view.animation (TaskId:294)
1>     495 android.support.v4.widget (TaskId:294)
1>     397 android.support.v7.app (TaskId:294)
1>    2410 android.support.v7.appcompat (TaskId:294)
1>    2410 android.support.v7.cardview (TaskId:294)
1>       8 android.support.v7.content.res (TaskId:294)
1>      18 android.support.v7.graphics.drawable (TaskId:294)
1>    2410 android.support.v7.recyclerview (TaskId:294)
1>       1 android.support.v7.text (TaskId:294)
1>       2 android.support.v7.transition (TaskId:294)
1>     124 android.support.v7.util (TaskId:294)
1>      77 android.support.v7.view (TaskId:294)
1>     248 android.support.v7.view.menu (TaskId:294)
1>    1398 android.support.v7.widget (TaskId:294)
1>      89 android.support.v7.widget.helper (TaskId:294)
1>       1 android.support.v7.widget.util (TaskId:294)
1>       5 android.text (TaskId:294)
1>       1 android.text.util (TaskId:294)
1>      14 android.util (TaskId:294)
1>      18 android.view (TaskId:294)
1>       8 android.view.accessibility (TaskId:294)
1>       1 android.view.inputmethod (TaskId:294)
1>       5 android.webkit (TaskId:294)
1>      21 android.widget (TaskId:294)
1>    2404 com.google.android.gms (TaskId:294)
1>      20 com.google.android.gms.actions (TaskId:294)
1>      13 com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier (TaskId:294)
1>      36 com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin (TaskId:294)
1>       6 com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal (TaskId:294)
1>    2404 com.google.android.gms.base (TaskId:294)
1>      98 com.google.android.gms.common (TaskId:294)
1>      95 com.google.android.gms.common.api (TaskId:294)
1>      41 com.google.android.gms.common.data (TaskId:294)
1>      46 com.google.android.gms.common.images (TaskId:294)
1>     188 com.google.android.gms.common.internal (TaskId:294)
1>       1 com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel (TaskId:294)
1>       4 com.google.android.gms.common.server (TaskId:294)
1>      12 com.google.android.gms.common.server.converter (TaskId:294)
1>      33 com.google.android.gms.common.server.response (TaskId:294)
1>      63 com.google.android.gms.common.stats (TaskId:294)
1>      22 com.google.android.gms.common.util (TaskId:294)
1>      27 com.google.android.gms.dynamic (TaskId:294)
1>       2 com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.flags (TaskId:294)
1>      16 com.google.android.gms.flags.impl (TaskId:294)
1>       6 com.google.android.gms.iid (TaskId:294)
1>    1341 com.google.android.gms.internal (TaskId:294)
1>       5 com.google.android.gms.location.places (TaskId:294)
1>      18 com.google.android.gms.phenotype (TaskId:294)
1>      11 com.google.android.gms.playlog.internal (TaskId:294)
1>       6 com.google.android.gms.security (TaskId:294)
1>      26 com.google.android.gms.signin.internal (TaskId:294)
1>    2452 com.google.android.gms.tasks (TaskId:294)
1>    2435 com.google.firebase (TaskId:294)
1>       2 com.google.firebase.auth (TaskId:294)
1>    2459 com.google.firebase.iid (TaskId:294)
1>    2437 com.google.firebase.messaging (TaskId:294)
1>    2495 com.joanzapata.pdfview (TaskId:294)
1>       8 com.joanzapata.pdfview.model (TaskId:294)
1>      39 com.joanzapata.pdfview.util (TaskId:294)
1>    2492 com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper (TaskId:294)
1>    1131 com.skytree.epub (TaskId:294)
1>     368 com.squareup.okhttp (TaskId:294)
1>      90 com.squareup.okhttp.internal (TaskId:294)
1>     133 com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http (TaskId:294)
1>       1 com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io (TaskId:294)
1>     243 com.squareup.okhttp.internal.spdy (TaskId:294)
1>      11 com.squareup.okhttp.internal.tls (TaskId:294)
1>     347 com.squareup.picasso (TaskId:294)
1>    2401 com.ytechwebschool.droid (TaskId:294)
1>       2 java.io (TaskId:294)
1>      12 java.lang (TaskId:294)
1>       7 java.lang.annotation (TaskId:294)
1>       6 java.net (TaskId:294)
1>       1 java.nio (TaskId:294)
1>       6 java.util (TaskId:294)
1>       4 java.util.concurrent (TaskId:294)
1>       3 java.util.logging (TaskId:294)
1>       2 md5019150c7713b24a447e4fd8c3f76632d (TaskId:294)
1>       2 md5048a04284979bff265231e98628579ce (TaskId:294)
1>       8 md520476b3d730a4692111560b01beafbf5 (TaskId:294)
1>       2 md5205d0916216d138654c77f637ee1cc90 (TaskId:294)
1>      12 md521020641efcec5bf9b0512907b92f249 (TaskId:294)
1>      10 md52335815dbfafa80b49f1a49c2a70d818 (TaskId:294)
1>       4 md526b7ac14cffc1a788e82c7b73f3add08 (TaskId:294)
1>       4 md531f8cc8d4d39b2fa02686ee0eb368905 (TaskId:294)
1>       8 md5471d110c8bb7ff37297374df784c2cee (TaskId:294)
1>       6 md55033ca37c678cdf20c14f110c9bacb80 (TaskId:294)
1>     178 md552b354c3816a29fbb90de6c8f0fdcd19 (TaskId:294)
1>       6 md552b8a35caf489e8e9cc4abcbc24b4c72 (TaskId:294)
1>       2 md55d8049a390a6f59c6033421d9a6a7cb8 (TaskId:294)
1>      18 md55f745489a55c1418869d471d93b5f35b (TaskId:294)
1>       4 md5636a41490577073255dce8c0a20bd415 (TaskId:294)
1>      10 md573df5bf65258bde5f06e24f6fe60f220 (TaskId:294)
1>       4 md5d0344be23ac987695f177aa1dab31949 (TaskId:294)
1>      16 md5de74fe60be74057a72a4e5ed2f8ed880 (TaskId:294)
1>       2 md5e424e6ea239d40c2a27b23ad851f2b02 (TaskId:294)
1>       4 md5ef453142d677b7c0ee97e9e15b9f6cda (TaskId:294)
1>       4 md5fb73fd704f950839995cd69b1931d746 (TaskId:294)
1>       6 mono (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.accounts (TaskId:294)
1>      12 mono.android.animation (TaskId:294)
1>      29 mono.android.app (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.bluetooth (TaskId:294)
1>      20 mono.android.content (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.database.sqlite (TaskId:294)
1>       6 mono.android.drm (TaskId:294)
1>       6 mono.android.gesture (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.graphics (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.graphics.drawable (TaskId:294)
1>       8 mono.android.hardware (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.hardware.display (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.hardware.input (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.inputmethodservice (TaskId:294)
1>       6 mono.android.location (TaskId:294)
1>      60 mono.android.media (TaskId:294)
1>      16 mono.android.media.audiofx (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.media.effect (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.media.midi (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.media.session (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.media.tv (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.net (TaskId:294)
1>       6 mono.android.net.nsd (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.net.sip (TaskId:294)
1>      18 mono.android.net.wifi.p2p (TaskId:294)
1>      10 mono.android.os (TaskId:294)
1>      10 mono.android.preference (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.renderscript (TaskId:294)
1>       6 mono.android.runtime (TaskId:294)
1>       6 mono.android.sax (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.speech (TaskId:294)
1>       4 mono.android.speech.tts (TaskId:294)
1>       8 mono.android.support.design.widget (TaskId:294)
1>       4 mono.android.support.v4.app (TaskId:294)
1>       4 mono.android.support.v4.content (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.support.v4.media.session (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.support.v4.os (TaskId:294)
1>      18 mono.android.support.v4.view (TaskId:294)
1>       4 mono.android.support.v4.view.accessibility (TaskId:294)
1>      12 mono.android.support.v4.widget (TaskId:294)
1>       6 mono.android.support.v7.app (TaskId:294)
1>      32 mono.android.support.v7.widget (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.text (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.transition (TaskId:294)
1>      66 mono.android.view (TaskId:294)
1>       4 mono.android.view.accessibility (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.view.animation (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.android.view.textservice (TaskId:294)
1>       8 mono.android.webkit (TaskId:294)
1>      72 mono.android.widget (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.com.google.android.gms.common.api (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.com.google.android.gms.common.images (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.com.google.android.gms.security (TaskId:294)
1>       6 mono.com.google.android.gms.tasks (TaskId:294)
1>       6 mono.com.joanzapata.pdfview.listener (TaskId:294)
1>       6 mono.com.joanzapata.pdfview.util (TaskId:294)
1>      26 mono.com.skytree.epub (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.com.squareup.picasso (TaskId:294)
1>       4 mono.java.lang (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.java.util (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.javax.xml.transform (TaskId:294)
1>       8 mono.org.vudroid.core.events (TaskId:294)
1>       8 mono.uk.co.senab.photoview (TaskId:294)
1>       2 mono.uk.co.senab.photoview.gestures (TaskId:294)
1>      83 okio (TaskId:294)
1>       2 opentk (TaskId:294)
1>       2 opentk.platform.android (TaskId:294)
1>       2 opentk_1_0 (TaskId:294)
1>       2 opentk_1_0.platform.android (TaskId:294)
1>      65 org.vudroid.core (TaskId:294)
1>       6 org.vudroid.core.events (TaskId:294)
1>       6 org.vudroid.core.models (TaskId:294)
1>       3 org.vudroid.core.multitouch (TaskId:294)
1>       1 org.vudroid.core.utils (TaskId:294)
1>       4 org.vudroid.pdfdroid.codec (TaskId:294)
1>    2455 uk.co.senab.photoview (TaskId:294)
1>      16 uk.co.senab.photoview.gestures (TaskId:294)
1>       1 uk.co.senab.photoview.log (TaskId:294)
1>       4 uk.co.senab.photoview.scrollerproxy (TaskId:294)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2.
1>    DexOutputs:  (TaskId:294)
1>Done executing task "CompileToDalvik" -- FAILED. (TaskId:294)
1>Done building target "_CompileToDalvikWithDx" in project "WebSchoolAndroid.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:147)
```

Anyone please help me . 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Need the *full error* that produces that error 2. Enable diagnostic level logging and perform a build and include the full exception/error in your question. .... i.e. Is it a multidex error, an old Proguard problem, Java version error, etc...

Comment: @SushiHangover I have added the output from Diagnostic . Please have a look. As it says that I need to enable Multi Dex but when I enable it shows another error file not found.

Comment: There are 65549 fields, so you **have** to enable multi-dex. What is the error that you get after enabling MultiDex?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got answer after 48 hours of struggle. Simply what I did was change the package name from **com.myexample.droid to com.myexample.mainapplication in AndroidMainfeast.Xml File at the line** `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.myexample.mainapplication" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="9">`, that did trick to me. Good luck to every one. To be clear please have a look this link ["trouble writing output: Too many field references: 70185; max is 65536. You may try using --multi-dex option." when building Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749654/trouble-writing-output-too-many-field-references-70185-max-is-65536-you-may).
and read this information

1. Do away with the need for library projects. Package everything into one monolithic structure.
2. Split the project files into multiple dex files.

   ## 1 goes against fundamental software principles of software development – code needs to be developed as re-usable libraries.

## 2 is a good long-term solution but is more complex.

The solution: A reasonable medium term solution emerged after understanding more closely. The significance of Package name within the manifest tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file is that it is used as a fully qualifying name to identify Android resources. It does not have anything to do with the package name for the java classes themselves.

I followed the same process and changed it and got successful build neither enabling MultiDex nor doing ProGuard. Remember my MaxHeapSize is 1G.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after I updated the Google Services packages (nuget).

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing false from True to false solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing false inside android.csproj from True to false solved the issue