# Firebase.AppIndexing and Firebase.Analytics conflict in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android, firebase-analytics, firebase-app-indexing

When I install both `Xamarin.Firebase.AppIndexing` and `Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics` in my `Xamain.Andriod` project, the build is always failed.

The build output

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2068,3):
>   error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2.

If I uninstall AppIndexing or Analytics, the solution can be built again.

Can anyone help me to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[edit: simply go to Android Properties, Android Options, Packaging tab then check "Enable Multi-Dex. And in the Advanced tab under "Java Max Heap Size" type 1G]

most probably it is caused by this,
["trouble writing output: Too many field references: 70185; max is 65536. You may try using --multi-dex option." when building Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749654/trouble-writing-output-too-many-field-references-70185-max-is-65536-you-may)
you passed the limit!

this one explains it well too: http://www.telerik.com/forums/java-exe-exited-with-code-2