# trouble writing output: Too many methods: 77742; max is 65536. By package:

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My project contains a single lib, but I am getting the error `trouble writing output: Too many methods: 77742; max is 65536. By package:` as suggested in other posts I deleted `-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m` from eclipse.ini.

Comment: You don't happen to have 77742 methods in a single class, do you?

Comment: its actually an external lib. android-4.0.1_r1.jar from grepcode.com

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to package too many methods into a single android application. You'll need to [refactor some of your code into plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15509415/632736), or remove methods you don't use.

Comment: how do we remove code form external jar file(ie android-4.0.1_r1.jar from grepcode.com). please tell me how to refactor the code.