# Android studio error code 2 UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

Tags: android, android-studio, error-code

i have a problem when i trying to compile an import android application to my android studio.

Where i wrong?

Error:Execution failed for task ':freshIM:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Users/Manuel/Desktop/Android/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/19.1.0/dx --dex --num-threads=4 --output /Users/Manuel/Desktop/Android/android-sdk-macosx/samples/FreshIM2/freshIM/build/intermediates/dex/debug /Users/Manuel/Desktop/Android/android-sdk-macosx/samples/FreshIM2/freshIM/build/intermediates/classes/debug /Users/Manuel/Desktop/Android/android-sdk-macosx/samples/FreshIM2/freshIM/build/intermediates/dependency-cache/debug /Users/Manuel/Desktop/Android/android-sdk-macosx/samples/FreshIM2/freshIM/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-1ae19b3a0bf802319e9e1b28ae0be5de00ebab02.jar /Users/Manuel/Desktop/Android/android-sdk-macosx/samples/FreshIM2/freshIM/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-538c6f1f64ea511ecd44305c634b96acf323665f.jar /Users/Manuel/Desktop/Android/android-sdk-macosx/samples/FreshIM2/freshIM/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-e107340d2d8eacb08585848b04409e8a30f816a9.jar /Users/Manuel/Desktop/Android/android-sdk-macosx/samples/FreshIM2/freshIM/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-fdf9350bdef43c6dfdaf1b1f8b6b5aaab33daaf3.jar /Users/Manuel/Desktop/Android/android-sdk-macosx/samples/FreshIM2/freshIM/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/sdk-1.0.1-830f4db143977ad24a452c5380e08f90b9a646a4.jar /Users/Manuel/Desktop/Android/android-sdk-macosx/samples/FreshIM2/freshIM/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/support-v4-19.1.0-421813bd2bfef69f908cede1f937984c36c82fd0.jar
>     Error Code:
>       2
>     Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:501)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:276)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:490)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:167)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15509415/3020568

Answer (score 2):

**There can only be 65536 methods per application.**

The Dalvik VM can have a maximum of 65536 methods per dex file

Try this link to resolve this issue 
http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html

As per the official blog **"Big apps can contain more than 64K method references, which is the maximum number of supported in a dex file. To get around this limitation, developers can partition part of the program into multiple secondary dex files, and load them at runtime."**